# Execute a function when page is loaded

Tags: jquery, function

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   $("#placeholder .flot-text .xAxis .tickLabel").css('height','90px','important');
});
```

Hi how do i execute this function as soon as the page is loaded??
This function is being called only when i refresh the page, but i want it to be called when ever the page is loaded.

Comment: `$(window).bind('load', ...)` should work fine. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UjwaE/). Your problem is probably somewhere else. Note the difference between executing something on page load and on DOMReady, which is what people are recommending in answers.

Comment: why `important`? no need as this css will be applied as inline styling.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Another `important` rule may override the inline style unless that is also `important`. Having said that; I'd generally try to avoid using `important` at all.

Comment: ya that will result in bad design.

Comment: If i give an alert then its working fine, else this wont be called first :(

Comment: Can you post the code which includes the alert. It will make us easy to understand :)

Comment: $(window).bind("load", function() {

alert('hi');

$("#placeholder .flot-text .xAxis .tickLabel").css('height','90px');
});

Comment: Now can you see any error in developer tool? (press `f12` on browser and go to console). and please explain what do you mean by "not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Write your code 
});
```

**Put Scripts at the Bottom**

*The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads. The HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that browsers download no more than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur in parallel. While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't start any other downloads, even on different hostnames.
In some situations it's not easy to move scripts to the bottom. If, for example, the script uses document.write to insert part of the page's content, it can't be moved lower in the page. There might also be scoping issues. In many cases, there are ways to workaround these situations.
An alternative suggestion that often comes up is to use deferred scripts. The DEFER attribute indicates that the script does not contain document.write, and is a clue to browsers that they can continue rendering. Unfortunately, Firefox doesn't support the DEFER attribute. In Internet Explorer, the script may be deferred, but not as much as desired. If a script can be deferred, it can also be moved to the bottom of the page. That will make your web pages load faster.*

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: Firefox 3.5 was the first version to support the `defer` attribute; Firefox 4 also supports the `async` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Like this by using **document.ready**

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $("#placeholder .flot-text .xAxis .tickLabel").css('height','90px','important');
});
```

or you can use **$(function)** like

```
$(function(){
    $("#placeholder .flot-text .xAxis .tickLabel").css('height','90px','important'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //execute ur code here.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $("#placeholder .flot-text .xAxis .tickLabel").css('height','90px','important');
});
```

## OR

```
$(function() {
     // Handler for .ready() called.
     $("#placeholder .flot-text .xAxis .tickLabel").css('height','90px','important');
    });
```

[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) - Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

[jQuery Document Ready Explained](http://www.surfingsuccess.com/jquery/document-ready.html)

Comment: Try replacing $ with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery you could use;

```
$(function(){
//Your code here
});
```